# Service IValidator Array

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, cqrs, fluentvalidation

My Razor Page project implement CQRS and FluentValidation, every Command or Query needs to be added in the Program.cs class like this:

> builder.Services.AddScoped<IValidator < GetPhonesQuery >, GetPhonesQueryValidator>();

Is there any way in which I create a Dictionary or something that allow me to save all the queries/commands classes and their validator class and iterating this Dictionary allow me to create a dynamic service?

Comment: "Alternatively you can register all validators in a specific assembly by using our Service Collection extensions. To do this you’ll need to install the FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions package and then call the appropriate AddValidators... extension method on the services collection. "

See this page https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/di.html#automatic-registration for more information (is literal citation from the documentation of fluentvalidation)